# File can be compiled, but won't run

Tags: java, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I can compile a file by pointing it to the library folder it uses for it using the command `javac -cp "path\to\lib\file.jar" FileName.java` but when I try to run it with `java FileName`, I receive the following stacktrace:

```
java SecureFileSample
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/voltage/securedata/enterprise/VeException
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.voltage.securedata.enterprise.VeException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 7 more
```

That means that this software can't be used or integrated with other software until I figure this out (adding this here because somehow Stack Overflow thinks "Can compile but won't run isn't clear enough" as a description). The expected behavior is the class to run (to execute the instructions it's given) but the regular commands for this, say `java FileName` won't work.

I've googled around, and the only answer I found (relate to the builder in the main class) matches exactly on how my builder is.

There is no package declaration in this file.

Comment: try `java -cp path/to/voltage/jarfile MyClass`

Comment: This returns `Error: Could not find or load main class SecureFileSample`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide the same classpath (which, presumably, contains the `VeException` class) with the `java` command. Additionally (to capture the discussion from the comments) don't forget to add the directory containing the compiled class:

```
java -cp "path\to\lib\file.jar;path\to\lib\" SecureFileSample
```

Comment: This returns a `Error: Could not find or load main class SecureFileSample` as well

Comment: @LukePerez did you fully qualify it with its package name?

Comment: I don't have any package declaration in this file at the moment.

Comment: @LukePerez that was dumb of me - you also need to include the directory containing the compiled class. Edited and fixed.

Comment: Not dumb at all, I don't think this is a very obvious Java thing. Let me try that.

Comment: @LukePerez unlike `jar` or `zip` files, you shouldn't specify `class` files in the classpath, only the directory containing them. I.e.: `java -cp "path\to\lib\file.jar;C:\Users\Voltage\lib" SecureFileSample`

Comment: Oooooh, gotcha! Let me try that.

Comment: EUREKA! Thanks, @Mureinik.